# use ms-access autokeys macro to toggle main menu, ribbon and navigation pane

Tags: ms-access

Trying to add this function to the Autokeys macro to toggle off main menu, ribbon and navigation pane:

```
Public Function nomenu ()
   DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
   DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon",acToolbarNo
End Function
```

The Autokeys macro is set up as:

Submacro: ^z
RunCode
  Function Name nomenu ()
End Submacro

Want to add this function plus another to have two "hot keys" to toggle on and off the menus and navigation pane.

Get following error message:
"The expression you entered has a function name that (DB name) can't find." Error number 2425.

Comment: I tested code and macro. Both work for me. Cannot replicate issue. Did you put function in a general module? Function has name different from module?

Comment: I misunderstood about the naming conventions.  Once I renamed the function to a different name, it worked.  THANKS!